# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 - When Overriding a method

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I'm trying to Mock a class for use in my test.

```
func testExample() {

    class SomeClassMock : SomeClass {
       override func doSomthing() ->Bool  {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

But every time I get this error:

**Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11**

Comment: Same thing happened to me.